# Given the equation $-1+rx+x^2-rx^3$, for what values of $r$ will the function have two zeroes?

Tags: polynomials

So by letting $f(x):=-1+rx+x^2-rx^3$, I was thinking of using the cubic discriminant and seeing where the zeroes are of that however this seems to be quite messy. Also, was thinking of finding the zeroes of $f$ and its derivative and utilising the result that tells me that a double root exists if and only if $f(\alpha)=f'(\alpha)=0$ where $\alpha$ is a root. However, are these the quickest ways for this kind of question? If not, then what would be instead?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{r}$ is a zero!

Comment: to see if it has two (real) solutions, you only need to find the zeroes of the derivative and then check if either of those are also zeroes of the function itself. If not, the function does not have exactly 2 zeroes.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. We have the zeroes of $f$ are $1/r$ and $\pm 1$. Then, when differentiating with respect to $x$, we obtain $r+2x-3rx^2$. Then, substituting the zeroes of $f$ in, we get $f'(1/r)=r-1/r$, $f'(1)=2-2r$ and $f'(-1)=-2-2r$. The zeroes are $\pm 1$. But then there is also one at $r=0$ right? Where does that one come from in the calculations?

Answer (score 2):

This factors easily:

$$f(x)=x^2-rx^3-1+rx=x^2(1-rx)-1(1-rx)=(1-rx)(x^2-1).$$

It shouldn't be too tricky from here.

Comment: So the zeroes of $f$ are $\pm 1$ and $1/r$. So then, substitute into the derivative and see if they are zeroes of the derivative too?

Comment: Why would you want to do that ? You already have the zeros of the function.

Comment: True, I guess I could just plot various graphs for the zeroes of the function and see where I get two roots

Comment: @thesmallprint You are complicating things. Plus and minus one are two roots. If the third root is equal to either of those there are only two distinct roots. Derivative need not come into it. Separately consider r=0

Comment: Oh yeah that's actually very true - all seems so silly now